# How to disconnect SQL client connection once crystal report is closed

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010, sqlclient

I'm currently using SAP Crystal Report 2013. I have a ODBC (RDO) connection setup and every time I run the Crystal Report from my native application (Progress 4GL Application), a new SQL DB connection gets established. However on closing the report, the SQL Client is not disconnected (i.e. the connection still remains). Every time I open a report a new connection is established and it never disconnects until I close the application.

I tried using the .close() , .dispose() in VB.net code on which my Crystal Report is setup. Nothings seems to help.

Please Advise.

Comment: Please elaborate your question and please share us what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
repo.Database.Dispose();